# Log URLs that Flash calls?

Tags: macos, mac, flash, url, logging

I want to log any URLs that are being called from Flash on my Mac. Any suggestions on tools that I could use? A nice TCP logger would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) and [HTTP Scoop](http://www.tuffcode.com/) are good options. They have very different approaches from each other, so one of them is likely to work for you. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Though not the friendliest tool, there's always [tcpdump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcpdump) which has the advantage of being built-in.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about Flash in the browse and you're using Firefox, a nice add-on is HttpFox... I use it all the time for monitoring HTTP requests.

I also like Charles that Avi Flax recommended above.  Charles has the advantage of running as a separate application as a real HTTP proxy, so it can capture HTTP traffic from any browser that's configured to use it as a proxy.